# PowerBI Dynamically Select the Latest Date when I refresh the Dashboard

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a PowerBI dashboard.

This dashboard has many tabs, those tabs they have a date slicer, and they're all in sync.

I want to achieve whenever I refresh the dashboard, either manually or scheduled refresh, the slicer will force select the most recent date, so the other tabs of the dashboard will in sync have the most recent date as well.

I have googled many different videos, topics, post about this. None of them have worked so far for me.

I have tried DAX function, DAX function the most common one is this or something similar

`IF((Date table[Date] = TODAY()),”Today “ , Date Table[Date]&””)`

The problem with this is it does not force select, whenever I refresh a new date pops up, the slicer stays at the old date.

I have also tried Chiclet slicer, which has a force select, but it does not in sync with the other tabs of the dashboard.

I know my idea may be a little too perfect for PowerBI use case, but if someone has any idea that can help me achieve this, it would be much appreciated!

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, this is not possible at the moment of writing. Slicers don't support dynamic selections.There are various other approaches possible, depending on your data model and your actual business goal.

When you write you want to force the slicer to select the last value - I suppose this is to always show the latest data on the dashboard (for a day, for a month?).

I would use a different approach to do that - one of the following:

- relative date filter (not a slicer)
- a slicer with **no** default selection and a measure that shows latest data only, if nothing is selected in the slicer
- a calculated column in a date table that shows, for instance, *Today* (or whatever) and that Today refers to the dates you want to see during refresh. Then you can fix your slicer on that Today value, which will refer to different dates upon each refresh.

There are multiple approaches to many problems, but first you'd need to define the actual business problem, as opposed to attempted solution :).